# Best performance for setting TextView color programmatically

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have a RecyclerView displaying Cardviews.  Each CardView has five (5) textViews.  Depending on the type of each card, I change the color of the text to either red, blue or green (default).  All of this is happening within my onBindViewHolder, so performance is critical to my user experience.  Here is what I do right now in my onBindViewHolder.

```
    //set text color per card type
        int int_textColor;
        String type = arrayListFiltered.get(position).getType().toLowerCase();
        String s_rating_type;
        if (!FormatFactory.isStringEmpty(type)){
            if (type.contains("featured")){
                int_textColor = R.color.red;
            }else if (type.contains("connector")){
                int_textColor = R.color.blue;
            }else{
                int_textColor = R.color.green;
            }
        }else{
            int_textColor =R.color.green;
        }
        setTextColor(recyclerViewHolder.tv_rating_type, int_textColor);
        setTextColor(recyclerViewHolder.tv_length, int_textColor);
        setTextColor(recyclerViewHolder.tv_name, int_textColor);
        setTextColor(recyclerViewHolder.tv_location, int_textColor);
        setTextColor(recyclerViewHolder.tv_summary, int_textColor);
```

and here is my setTextColor method

```
private void setTextColor(TextView tv, int color){
    tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tv.getContext(), color));
}
```

Many ways exist to change text color, and I have been unable to find any discussion regarding the method that provides the best performance.  Even though this code works just fine, I would rewrite it for a small performance gain.

Comment: Did you witness any lag or bad performance while using this code, on low-end device only or all of them?

Comment: My recommend if you want to refactor it, store `int_textColor` as a variable inside your model. This way, you use 5 extra `int` in the memory to save about 3 * 5 if-else check. The gap gets bigger if your number of models or `TextView` increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can override the method `getItemViewType` of adapter, and inflate different layout in different color. Let the adapter handle the color change instead of changing color dynamically.

for example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int rid;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0: // for featured type
                rid= R.layout.red;
                break;
            case 1 : // for connector type
                rid= R.layout.blue;
                break;
            default:
                rid= R.layout.green;
                break;
        }
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(id, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return arrayListFiltered.get(position).getType(); // need int type
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why would you inflate additional layouts to avoid a cheap operation like setting text color?